# How can I check if a User Account group exists through powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Something like this :

```
if(GroupExists("Admins")) // <-- How can I do this line ?
{
    ([ADSI]"WinNT://$_/Admins,group").add($User)
}
else
{
    $Group = Read-Host 'Enter the User Group :'
    ([ADSI]"WinNT://$_/$Group,group").add($User)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Exists static method as follows:

```
[ADSI]::Exists("WinNT://localhost/Administrators")
```

To get a True/False result you can wrap into try/catch statement.

```
$result = try { [ADSI]::Exists("WinNT://localhost/Administrators") } catch { $False }
```

or in a if/then statement you'll need to wrap it inside a `$()`

```
if ( $(try {[ADSI]::Exists("WinNT://localhost/Administrators")} catch {$False}) ) {
    write-host "good"
    }
else {
    write-host "bad"
    }
```